# Google Street View with deviceorientation (Full Tilt)

Tags: google-maps, google-street-view, device-orientation

I am trying to create a Google Street View that can be controlled via a devices orientation.

I am using [Full Tilt](https://github.com/adtile/Full-Tilt/wiki/Full-Tilt-API-Documentation) to normalize devices / OS and it seems to be doing a really good job. In fact, it seems very close indeed to the solution I'm after.

However, at various positions, the view seems to jump rapidly (although it seems to resolve to the correct location) and is not as smooth as I would like. This seems particularly obvious if the device is held at around 90 degrees (upright) and rotated slightly to the left or right.

[JS Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/mb56r3cy/3/) has an example and would need to be viewed on a mobile device or tablet to see the effect. Following the link further down will only work if you can get to the edit mode where the deviceorientation is allowed to work.

Any ideas if there is a way to resolve this? Or if I'm on to a loser here?

```js
var map;

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function () {
 
  // Set up map
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 9,
    // Initial
    center:{
      lat: 35.6735408,
      lng: 139.570305,
    },
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    streetViewControl: true,
  });
  
  // Set up street view
  google.maps.streetViewViewer = 'photosphere';
  var street_view = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('street-view'), {
    addressControl: false,
    fullscreenControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
  });
  street_view.setPano('2qVB_HA94-kQCAzwffO44g');
  
  // When street view ready, update map position and pov
  street_view.addListener('status_changed', function(){
    var position = street_view.getPosition();
    if( map ){
      map.setCenter(position);
      map.setStreetView(street_view);
    }
  });
  
  // FULL TILT ORIENTATION
  var promise = new FULLTILT.getDeviceOrientation({ 'type': 'world' });

  var deviceOrientation;

  promise
  .then(function(controller) {
    deviceOrientation = controller;
  })
  .catch(function(message) {
    console.error(message);
  });

  (function draw() {

    if (deviceOrientation) {

      var euler = deviceOrientation.getScreenAdjustedEuler();

   //  debug
   console.log('alpha: %d, beta: %d, gamma: %d', euler.alpha, euler.beta, euler.gamma);
      document.getElementById('alpha').innerHTML = euler.alpha.toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById('beta').innerHTML = euler.beta.toFixed(2);
      document.getElementById('gamma').innerHTML = euler.gamma.toFixed(2);
      
      // Set POV
      if( euler.alpha != 0 && euler.beta != 0 && euler.gamma !=0 ){
       street_view.setPov({
          heading: euler.alpha*-1,
          pitch: euler.beta-90,
        });
      }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  })();

});

/*! Full Tilt v0.5.2 / http://github.com/richtr/Full-Tilt */
!function(a){function b(a){return a=+a,0===a||isNaN(a)?a:a>0?1:-1}function c(a){var b=new Promise(function(b,c){var d=function(e){setTimeout(function(){a&&a.data?b():e>=20?c():d(++e)},50)};d(0)});return b}function d(){o=n?(a.screen.orientation.angle||0)*j:(a.orientation||0)*j}function e(a){l.orientation.data=a;for(var b in l.orientation.callbacks)l.orientation.callbacks[b].call(this)}function f(a){l.motion.data=a;for(var b in l.motion.callbacks)l.motion.callbacks[b].call(this)}if(void 0===a.FULLTILT||null===a.FULLTILT){var g=Math.PI,h=g/2,i=2*g,j=g/180,k=180/g,l={orientation:{active:!1,callbacks:[],data:void 0},motion:{active:!1,callbacks:[],data:void 0}},m=!1,n=a.screen&&a.screen.orientation&&void 0!==a.screen.orientation.angle&&null!==a.screen.orientation.angle?!0:!1,o=(n?a.screen.orientation.angle:a.orientation||0)*j,p=h,q=g,r=i/3,s=-h,t={};t.version="0.5.2",t.getDeviceOrientation=function(a){var b=new Promise(function(b,d){var e=new t.DeviceOrientation(a);e.start();var f=new c(l.orientation);f.then(function(){e._alphaAvailable=l.orientation.data.alpha&&null!==l.orientation.data.alpha,e._betaAvailable=l.orientation.data.beta&&null!==l.orientation.data.beta,e._gammaAvailable=l.orientation.data.gamma&&null!==l.orientation.data.gamma,b(e)}).catch(function(){e.stop(),d("DeviceOrientation is not supported")})});return b},t.getDeviceMotion=function(a){var b=new Promise(function(b,d){var e=new t.DeviceMotion(a);e.start();var f=new c(l.motion);f.then(function(){e._accelerationXAvailable=l.motion.data.acceleration&&l.motion.data.acceleration.x,e._accelerationYAvailable=l.motion.data.acceleration&&l.motion.data.acceleration.y,e._accelerationZAvailable=l.motion.data.acceleration&&l.motion.data.acceleration.z,e._accelerationIncludingGravityXAvailable=l.motion.data.accelerationIncludingGravity&&l.motion.data.accelerationIncludingGravity.x,e._accelerationIncludingGravityYAvailable=l.motion.data.accelerationIncludingGravity&&l.motion.data.accelerationIncludingGravity.y,e._accelerationIncludingGravityZAvailable=l.motion.data.accelerationIncludingGravity&&l.motion.data.accelerationIncludingGravity.z,e._rotationRateAlphaAvailable=l.motion.data.rotationRate&&l.motion.data.rotationRate.alpha,e._rotationRateBetaAvailable=l.motion.data.rotationRate&&l.motion.data.rotationRate.beta,e._rotationRateGammaAvailable=l.motion.data.rotationRate&&l.motion.data.rotationRate.gamma,b(e)}).catch(function(){e.stop(),d("DeviceMotion is not supported")})});return b},t.Quaternion=function(a,c,d,e){var f;this.set=function(a,b,c,d){this.x=a||0,this.y=b||0,this.z=c||0,this.w=d||1},this.copy=function(a){this.x=a.x,this.y=a.y,this.z=a.z,this.w=a.w},this.setFromEuler=function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,k,l,m;return function(n){return n=n||{},c=(n.alpha||0)*j,a=(n.beta||0)*j,b=(n.gamma||0)*j,f=c/2,d=a/2,e=b/2,g=Math.cos(d),h=Math.cos(e),i=Math.cos(f),k=Math.sin(d),l=Math.sin(e),m=Math.sin(f),this.set(k*h*i-g*l*m,g*l*i+k*h*m,g*h*m+k*l*i,g*h*i-k*l*m),this.normalize(),this}}(),this.setFromRotationMatrix=function(){var a;return function(c){return a=c.elements,this.set(.5*Math.sqrt(1+a[0]-a[4]-a[8])*b(a[7]-a[5]),.5*Math.sqrt(1-a[0]+a[4]-a[8])*b(a[2]-a[6]),.5*Math.sqrt(1-a[0]-a[4]+a[8])*b(a[3]-a[1]),.5*Math.sqrt(1+a[0]+a[4]+a[8])),this}}(),this.multiply=function(a){return f=t.Quaternion.prototype.multiplyQuaternions(this,a),this.copy(f),this},this.rotateX=function(a){return f=t.Quaternion.prototype.rotateByAxisAngle(this,[1,0,0],a),this.copy(f),this},this.rotateY=function(a){return f=t.Quaternion.prototype.rotateByAxisAngle(this,[0,1,0],a),this.copy(f),this},this.rotateZ=function(a){return f=t.Quaternion.prototype.rotateByAxisAngle(this,[0,0,1],a),this.copy(f),this},this.normalize=function(){return t.Quaternion.prototype.normalize(this)},this.set(a,c,d,e)},t.Quaternion.prototype={constructor:t.Quaternion,multiplyQuaternions:function(){var a=new t.Quaternion;return function(b,c){var d=b.x,e=b.y,f=b.z,g=b.w,h=c.x,i=c.y,j=c.z,k=c.w;return a.set(d*k+g*h+e*j-f*i,e*k+g*i+f*h-d*j,f*k+g*j+d*i-e*h,g*k-d*h-e*i-f*j),a}}(),normalize:function(a){var b=Math.sqrt(a.x*a.x+a.y*a.y+a.z*a.z+a.w*a.w);return 0===b?(a.x=0,a.y=0,a.z=0,a.w=1):(b=1/b,a.x*=b,a.y*=b,a.z*=b,a.w*=b),a},rotateByAxisAngle:function(){var a,b,c=new t.Quaternion,d=new t.Quaternion;return function(e,f,g){return a=(g||0)/2,b=Math.sin(a),d.set((f[0]||0)*b,(f[1]||0)*b,(f[2]||0)*b,Math.cos(a)),c=t.Quaternion.prototype.multiplyQuaternions(e,d),t.Quaternion.prototype.normalize(c)}}()},t.RotationMatrix=function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i){var k;this.elements=new Float32Array(9),this.identity=function(){return this.set(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1),this},this.set=function(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i){this.elements[0]=a||1,this.elements[1]=b||0,this.elements[2]=c||0,this.elements[3]=d||0,this.elements[4]=e||1,this.elements[5]=f||0,this.elements[6]=g||0,this.elements[7]=h||0,this.elements[8]=i||1},this.copy=function(a){this.elements[0]=a.elements[0],this.elements[1]=a.elements[1],this.elements[2]=a.elements[2],this.elements[3]=a.elements[3],this.elements[4]=a.elements[4],this.elements[5]=a.elements[5],this.elements[6]=a.elements[6],this.elements[7]=a.elements[7],this.elements[8]=a.elements[8]},this.setFromEuler=function(){var a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i;return function(k){return k=k||{},c=(k.alpha||0)*j,a=(k.beta||0)*j,b=(k.gamma||0)*j,d=Math.cos(a),e=Math.cos(b),f=Math.cos(c),g=Math.sin(a),h=Math.sin(b),i=Math.sin(c),this.set(f*e-i*g*h,-d*i,e*i*g+f*h,e*i+f*g*h,f*d,i*h-f*e*g,-d*h,g,d*e),this.normalize(),this}}(),this.setFromQuaternion=function(){var a,b,c,d;return function(e){return a=e.w*e.w,b=e.x*e.x,c=e.y*e.y,d=e.z*e.z,this.set(a+b-c-d,2*(e.x*e.y-e.w*e.z),2*(e.x*e.z+e.w*e.y),2*(e.x*e.y+e.w*e.z),a-b+c-d,2*(e.y*e.z-e.w*e.x),2*(e.x*e.z-e.w*e.y),2*(e.y*e.z+e.w*e.x),a-b-c+d),this}}(),this.multiply=function(a){return k=t.RotationMatrix.prototype.multiplyMatrices(this,a),this.copy(k),this},this.rotateX=function(a){return k=t.RotationMatrix.prototype.rotateByAxisAngle(this,[1,0,0],a),this.copy(k),this},this.rotateY=function(a){return k=t.RotationMatrix.prototype.rotateByAxisAngle(this,[0,1,0],a),this.copy(k),this},this.rotateZ=function(a){return k=t.RotationMatrix.prototype.rotateByAxisAngle(this,[0,0,1],a),this.copy(k),this},this.normalize=function(){return t.RotationMatrix.prototype.normalize(this)},this.set(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)},t.RotationMatrix.prototype={constructor:t.RotationMatrix,multiplyMatrices:function(){var a,b,c=new t.RotationMatrix;return function(d,e){return a=d.elements,b=e.elements,c.set(a[0]*b[0]+a[1]*b[3]+a[2]*b[6],a[0]*b[1]+a[1]*b[4]+a[2]*b[7],a[0]*b[2]+a[1]*b[5]+a[2]*b[8],a[3]*b[0]+a[4]*b[3]+a[5]*b[6],a[3]*b[1]+a[4]*b[4]+a[5]*b[7],a[3]*b[2]+a[4]*b[5]+a[5]*b[8],a[6]*b[0]+a[7]*b[3]+a[8]*b[6],a[6]*b[1]+a[7]*b[4]+a[8]*b[7],a[6]*b[2]+a[7]*b[5]+a[8]*b[8]),c}}(),normalize:function(a){var b=a.elements,c=b[0]*b[4]*b[8]-b[0]*b[5]*b[7]-b[1]*b[3]*b[8]+b[1]*b[5]*b[6]+b[2]*b[3]*b[7]-b[2]*b[4]*b[6];return b[0]/=c,b[1]/=c,b[2]/=c,b[3]/=c,b[4]/=c,b[5]/=c,b[6]/=c,b[7]/=c,b[8]/=c,a.elements=b,a},rotateByAxisAngle:function(){var a,b,c=new t.RotationMatrix,d=new t.RotationMatrix,e=!1;return function(f,g,h){return d.identity(),e=!1,a=Math.sin(h),b=Math.cos(h),1===g[0]&&0===g[1]&&0===g[2]?(e=!0,d.elements[4]=b,d.elements[5]=-a,d.elements[7]=a,d.elements[8]=b):1===g[1]&&0===g[0]&&0===g[2]?(e=!0,d.elements[0]=b,d.elements[2]=a,d.elements[6]=-a,d.elements[8]=b):1===g[2]&&0===g[0]&&0===g[1]&&(e=!0,d.elements[0]=b,d.elements[1]=-a,d.elements[3]=a,d.elements[4]=b),e?(c=t.RotationMatrix.prototype.multiplyMatrices(f,d),c=t.RotationMatrix.prototype.normalize(c)):c=f,c}}()},t.Euler=function(a,b,c){this.set=function(a,b,c){this.alpha=a||0,this.beta=b||0,this.gamma=c||0},this.copy=function(a){this.alpha=a.alpha,this.beta=a.beta,this.gamma=a.gamma},this.setFromRotationMatrix=function(){var a,b,c,d;return function(e){a=e.elements,a[8]>0?(b=Math.atan2(-a[1],a[4]),c=Math.asin(a[7]),d=Math.atan2(-a[6],a[8])):a[8]<0?(b=Math.atan2(a[1],-a[4]),c=-Math.asin(a[7]),c+=c>=0?-g:g,d=Math.atan2(a[6],-a[8])):a[6]>0?(b=Math.atan2(-a[1],a[4]),c=Math.asin(a[7]),d=-h):a[6]<0?(b=Math.atan2(a[1],-a[4]),c=-Math.asin(a[7]),c+=c>=0?-g:g,d=-h):(b=Math.atan2(a[3],a[0]),c=a[7]>0?h:-h,d=0),0>b&&(b+=i),b*=k,c*=k,d*=k,this.set(b,c,d)}}(),this.setFromQuaternion=function(){var a,b,c;return function(d){var e=d.w*d.w,f=d.x*d.x,j=d.y*d.y,l=d.z*d.z,m=e+f+j+l,n=d.w*d.x+d.y*d.z,o=1e-6;if(n>(.5-o)*m)a=2*Math.atan2(d.y,d.w),b=h,c=0;else if((-.5+o)*m>n)a=-2*Math.atan2(d.y,d.w),b=-h,c=0;else{var p=e-f+j-l,q=2*(d.w*d.z-d.x*d.y),r=e-f-j+l,s=2*(d.w*d.y-d.x*d.z);r>0?(a=Math.atan2(q,p),b=Math.asin(2*n/m),c=Math.atan2(s,r)):(a=Math.atan2(-q,-p),b=-Math.asin(2*n/m),b+=0>b?g:-g,c=Math.atan2(-s,-r))}0>a&&(a+=i),a*=k,b*=k,c*=k,this.set(a,b,c)}}(),this.rotateX=function(a){return t.Euler.prototype.rotateByAxisAngle(this,[1,0,0],a),this},this.rotateY=function(a){return t.Euler.prototype.rotateByAxisAngle(this,[0,1,0],a),this},this.rotateZ=function(a){return t.Euler.prototype.rotateByAxisAngle(this,[0,0,1],a),this},this.set(a,b,c)},t.Euler.prototype={constructor:t.Euler,rotateByAxisAngle:function(){var a=new t.RotationMatrix;return function(b,c,d){return a.setFromEuler(b),a=t.RotationMatrix.prototype.rotateByAxisAngle(a,c,d),b.setFromRotationMatrix(a),b}}()},t.DeviceOrientation=function(b){this.options=b||{};var c=0,d=200,e=0,f=10;if(this.alphaOffsetScreen=0,this.alphaOffsetDevice=void 0,"game"===this.options.type){var g=function(b){return null!==b.alpha&&(this.alphaOffsetDevice=new t.Euler(b.alpha,0,0),this.alphaOffsetDevice.rotateZ(-o),++e>=f)?void a.removeEventListener("deviceorientation",g,!1):void(++c>=d&&a.removeEventListener("deviceorientation",g,!1))}.bind(this);a.addEventListener("deviceorientation",g,!1)}else if("world"===this.options.type){var h=function(b){return b.absolute!==!0&&void 0!==b.webkitCompassAccuracy&&null!==b.webkitCompassAccuracy&&+b.webkitCompassAccuracy>=0&&+b.webkitCompassAccuracy<50&&(this.alphaOffsetDevice=new t.Euler(b.webkitCompassHeading,0,0),this.alphaOffsetDevice.rotateZ(o),this.alphaOffsetScreen=o,++e>=f)?void a.removeEventListener("deviceorientation",h,!1):void(++c>=d&&a.removeEventListener("deviceorientation",h,!1))}.bind(this);a.addEventListener("deviceorientation",h,!1)}},t.DeviceOrientation.prototype={constructor:t.DeviceOrientation,start:function(b){b&&"[object Function]"==Object.prototype.toString.call(b)&&l.orientation.callbacks.push(b),m||(n?a.screen.orientation.addEventListener("change",d,!1):a.addEventListener("orientationchange",d,!1)),l.orientation.active||(a.addEventListener("deviceorientation",e,!1),l.orientation.active=!0)},stop:function(){l.orientation.active&&(a.removeEventListener("deviceorientation",e,!1),l.orientation.active=!1)},listen:function(a){this.start(a)},getFixedFrameQuaternion:function(){var a=new t.Euler,b=new t.RotationMatrix,c=new t.Quaternion;return function(){var d=l.orientation.data||{alpha:0,beta:0,gamma:0},e=d.alpha;return this.alphaOffsetDevice&&(b.setFromEuler(this.alphaOffsetDevice),b.rotateZ(-this.alphaOffsetScreen),a.setFromRotationMatrix(b),a.alpha<0&&(a.alpha+=360),e-=a.alpha),a.set(e,d.beta,d.gamma),c.setFromEuler(a),c}}(),getScreenAdjustedQuaternion:function(){var a;return function(){return a=this.getFixedFrameQuaternion(),a.rotateZ(-o),a}}(),getFixedFrameMatrix:function(){var a=new t.Euler,b=new t.RotationMatrix;return function(){var c=l.orientation.data||{alpha:0,beta:0,gamma:0},d=c.alpha;return this.alphaOffsetDevice&&(b.setFromEuler(this.alphaOffsetDevice),b.rotateZ(-this.alphaOffsetScreen),a.setFromRotationMatrix(b),a.alpha<0&&(a.alpha+=360),d-=a.alpha),a.set(d,c.beta,c.gamma),b.setFromEuler(a),b}}(),getScreenAdjustedMatrix:function(){var a;return function(){return a=this.getFixedFrameMatrix(),a.rotateZ(-o),a}}(),getFixedFrameEuler:function(){var a,b=new t.Euler;return function(){return a=this.getFixedFrameMatrix(),b.setFromRotationMatrix(a),b}}(),getScreenAdjustedEuler:function(){var a,b=new t.Euler;return function(){return a=this.getScreenAdjustedMatrix(),b.setFromRotationMatrix(a),b}}(),isAbsolute:function(){return l.orientation.data&&l.orientation.data.absolute===!0?!0:!1},getLastRawEventData:function(){return l.orientation.data||{}},_alphaAvailable:!1,_betaAvailable:!1,_gammaAvailable:!1,isAvailable:function(a){switch(a){case this.ALPHA:return this._alphaAvailable;case this.BETA:return this._betaAvailable;case this.GAMMA:return this._gammaAvailable}},ALPHA:"alpha",BETA:"beta",GAMMA:"gamma"},t.DeviceMotion=function(a){this.options=a||{}},t.DeviceMotion.prototype={constructor:t.DeviceMotion,start:function(b){b&&"[object Function]"==Object.prototype.toString.call(b)&&l.motion.callbacks.push(b),m||(n?a.screen.orientation.addEventListener("change",d,!1):a.addEventListener("orientationchange",d,!1)),l.motion.active||(a.addEventListener("devicemotion",f,!1),l.motion.active=!0)},stop:function(){l.motion.active&&(a.removeEventListener("devicemotion",f,!1),l.motion.active=!1)},listen:function(a){this.start(a)},getScreenAdjustedAcceleration:function(){var a=l.motion.data&&l.motion.data.acceleration?l.motion.data.acceleration:{x:0,y:0,z:0},b={};switch(o){case p:b.x=-a.y,b.y=a.x;break;case q:b.x=-a.x,b.y=-a.y;break;case r:case s:b.x=a.y,b.y=-a.x;break;default:b.x=a.x,b.y=a.y}return b.z=a.z,b},getScreenAdjustedAccelerationIncludingGravity:function(){var a=l.motion.data&&l.motion.data.accelerationIncludingGravity?l.motion.data.accelerationIncludingGravity:{x:0,y:0,z:0},b={};switch(o){case p:b.x=-a.y,b.y=a.x;break;case q:b.x=-a.x,b.y=-a.y;break;case r:case s:b.x=a.y,b.y=-a.x;break;default:b.x=a.x,b.y=a.y}return b.z=a.z,b},getScreenAdjustedRotationRate:function(){var a=l.motion.data&&l.motion.data.rotationRate?l.motion.data.rotationRate:{alpha:0,beta:0,gamma:0},b={};switch(o){case p:b.beta=-a.gamma,b.gamma=a.beta;break;case q:b.beta=-a.beta,b.gamma=-a.gamma;break;case r:case s:b.beta=a.gamma,b.gamma=-a.beta;break;default:b.beta=a.beta,b.gamma=a.gamma}return b.alpha=a.alpha,b},getLastRawEventData:function(){return l.motion.data||{}},_accelerationXAvailable:!1,_accelerationYAvailable:!1,_accelerationZAvailable:!1,_accelerationIncludingGravityXAvailable:!1,_accelerationIncludingGravityYAvailable:!1,_accelerationIncludingGravityZAvailable:!1,_rotationRateAlphaAvailable:!1,_rotationRateBetaAvailable:!1,_rotationRateGammaAvailable:!1,isAvailable:function(a){switch(a){case this.ACCELERATION_X:return this._accelerationXAvailable;case this.ACCELERATION_Y:return this._accelerationYAvailable;case this.ACCELERATION_Z:return this._accelerationZAvailable;case this.ACCELERATION_INCLUDING_GRAVITY_X:return this._accelerationIncludingGravityXAvailable;case this.ACCELERATION_INCLUDING_GRAVITY_Y:return this._accelerationIncludingGravityYAvailable;case this.ACCELERATION_INCLUDING_GRAVITY_Z:return this._accelerationIncludingGravityZAvailable;case this.ROTATION_RATE_ALPHA:return this._rotationRateAlphaAvailable;case this.ROTATION_RATE_BETA:return this._rotationRateBetaAvailable;case this.ROTATION_RATE_GAMMA:return this._rotationRateGammaAvailable}},ACCELERATION_X:"accelerationX",ACCELERATION_Y:"accelerationY",ACCELERATION_Z:"accelerationZ",ACCELERATION_INCLUDING_GRAVITY_X:"accelerationIncludingGravityX",ACCELERATION_INCLUDING_GRAVITY_Y:"accelerationIncludingGravityY",ACCELERATION_INCLUDING_GRAVITY_Z:"accelerationIncludingGravityZ",ROTATION_RATE_ALPHA:"rotationRateAlpha",ROTATION_RATE_BETA:"rotationRateBeta",ROTATION_RATE_GAMMA:"rotationRateGamma"},a.FULLTILT=t}}(window);
```

```css
#map{
  width: 200px; height: 200px; position: absolute; right: 20px; bottom: 20px;
}
#street-view{
  width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
}
#debug{
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid white; color: white;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="street-view"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="debug">
  alpha: <span id="alpha"></span> | 
  beta: <span id="beta"></span> | 
  gamma: <span id="gamma"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Have exactly the same issue. It seems we have the same problem.

What I found out is that it only occurs in portrait mode, not in landscape mode. Which I find weird. Found no solution so far...